# Android version 6.0 not correctly syncing outlook contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, exchange, outlook

I'm using a Motorola g2, and as the title suggests, I'm having an annoying sync issue with contacts.

What I've done is I've installed outlook and set that to sync contacts to my phone. Only problem is, when I create a contact in my default app, it doesn't update them on outlook (and as such, any data added in the default app disappears when I sync).

This is an incredibly annoying issue and I don't know how to solve it. I've googled the issue but the only thing close to what I want is on a different android version and the option isn't there

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got in touch with support.

They said the app was design like this. You can show your contacts in Android but they are read only.

Unfortunately some apps don't play well this rule and make were think it will sync a new contact to cloud. Believe me, it won't.

I'm still trying to find an alternative but in Outlook there is no way.

[image: read only account]